# "Seit..." sentence in German

Tags: standard-german, past

Which one is correct?

> Seit eine woche, bin ich aus Berlin zurückbekommen.

> Es ist eine Woche seit ich uns Berlin zurückgekommen bin

Comment: You might want to consider the difference between "seit" and "vor" with your example. "Seit" refers to a state or a prolonged activity, while "vor" refers to a point in time or a finished activity. If you say "Seit einer Woche bin ich aus Berlin zurückgekommen", you imply that the coming back took all week ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None.

The first one should be

> Seit einer Woche bin ich aus Berlin zurück.

I assume "zurückbekommen" is simply a typo. Commas do not occur after expressions of time. "seit" requires genitive and describes a an ongoing state. Since you haven't been returning for an entire week, you should use "zurück" instead.

Second one must be

> Es ist eine Woche her, seit ich aus Berlin zurückgekommen bin.

"uns" doesn't make any sense and should be "aus" — typo? To express how much time has passed since something occurred the expression "es ist ... her" is used. The "her" cannot be omitted. A comma must be inserted after "her" because this is the main clause (it contains a finite verb). This sentence is rather colloquial. You can replace "seit" with "dass" to improve, but I would probably prefer the first sentence.

Comment: No you can't say *"Es ist eine Woche her, **seit** ich aus Berlin zurückgekommen bin."* (this would say it's one week ago since I came... which is not correct) it must be **dass**. This version is possible: *"Es ist eine Woche vergangen, seit ich aus Berlin zurückgekommen bin."* (one week has passed since... - different meaning than the first phrase). But both sounds clumsy, too much effort to express what has happened.

Comment: @puck Do you have any source for this? German is a language with wide variety. Claiming something's wrong without some reference is mostly not a good idea. This construction doesn't sound unnatural to my Austria/Swiss accustomed ears at all.

Comment: @puck OP indeed lists Vienna as his location in his profile. Maybe this construction is more/only common in Austria.

Comment: Well, indeed it could be a valid and known way to say that in some regions, if "es ist eine Woche her..." has the same meaning as "es ist eine Woche vergangen...". Such details are hard to be discussed in a forum like this. Besides that it's also quite hard to prove something is wrong. Imagine how large a collection of "words not to be placed after each other" would be ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to say it is

> Vor einer Woche bin ich aus Berlin zurückgekommen.